# What does getSessionOpenCount() - getSessionCloseCount() represent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using HibernateStatistics to monitor session leakage. And to monitor session leakage I am relying on this

```
hibernateStatistics.getSessionOpenCount() - hibernateStatistics.getSessionCloseCount()
```

In my application this numbers keeps on increasing.So I have three specific questions

> 1.What does this indicate?Does it indicate that there is a session leak in my application?
>
> 2.How can I diagonse the parts of application which is causing this leak?Is there some tool
>
> 3.What does this number represents?Does it represents total no of open connection with DB?

Comment: For monitoring it is fine, but as your problem concern why are you not just use connection pool to manage connections.

Comment: @commit I am using DBCP as a Data Source with Spring+Hibernate.

Comment: DBCP is not recommended for production use as it has many issues, you should look for C3P0 or other.

Comment: @commit sure will try to do that.Do you some idea on above question?